# Targum Yonason on cutting the beard

Tags: shaving

Where exactly does the Targum Yonason say that cutting ones beard with a scissors is assur, as quoted in R' Chaim Kanievsky's Orchos Yosher?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Reuven Chaim Klein wrote an article on this entire subject and quotes different places where the Targum writes this, [To quote Rabbi Klein](https://ohr.edu/this_week/the_anatomy_of_a_mitzvah/9811):

> The Targum known as Yonatan (to Lev. 19:27, Num. 6:19) uses variations of galav when rendering cognates of the Hebrew giluach into Aramaic, and again [(to Num. 8:7)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.8.7?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Targum_Jonathan_on_Numbers.8.7&lang2=bi) uses galav as a translation of the Hebrew word ta'ar (“razor”). Elsewhere, the Targum (to [Joshua 5:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.5.2?lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Joshua&lang2=en), Jer. 48:37, see also Bereishet Rabbah 31:8) again uses variants of galav in this context of razors and cutting. All of this suggests that perhaps galav is an Aramaic word. However, Rashi and Mahari Kara (to Yechezkel 5:1) explain that galav actually comes from Greek. After much searching, I have not found any Greek word which fits this description, but I did find that Dr. Alexander Kohut (1842–1894) suggests changing Rashi’s wording to refer to Arabic instead of Greek. That said, Dr. Chaim Tawil notes that galav is clearly a loanword from the Akkadian gallabu ("barber").
>
> Other scholars connect the triliteral root GIMMEL-LAMMED-BET to
> similar Hebrew roots. For example, Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch (to Ps.
> 74:6) connects this root to KUF-LAMMED-PEH (via the interchangeability
> of GIMMEL and KUF, and that of BET and PEH), which means “to peel” in
> Rabbinic Hebrew. Indeed, “haircutting” which reveals one’s
> previously-covered epidermis can be similar to “peeling” away the skin
> or covering of something. Rabbi David Golumb in Targumna (to Num.
> 21:29) argues that galav is a metathesized form of gvul (“border”),
> which may be better understood in light of the possible connection
> between sapar and sfar (see below).
>
> Speaking of the word sapar, although this term does not appear in the
> Bible, it has become the most popular term for the topic that we are
> discussing, because in Modern Hebrew, sapar means “barber” and
> tisporet means “haircut.” But where does this word come from?
>
> If you look closely at Targum Oneklos and Targum Yonatan, you will
> notice an inconsistency in how they render the Hebrew giluach into the
> Aramaic: Sometimes they translate giluach into sapar, and sometimes
> they simply leave the verb in its original Hebrew form as a cognate of
> giluach. Rabbi Eliyahu HaBachur (1469-1549) in Meturgaman notes this
> inconsistency and also points out that the Targumic term maspar for
> “razor” (see Targum to Num. 6:5, Judges 13:5) is also derived from
> this root. Interestingly, Targum Neofiti is more consistent than the
> other Targumim in always rendering giluach as sapar.